# Need to Make CDockablePane Background Transparent in c++ MFC

Tags: c++, class, mfc, transparent

I'm developing an application in **MFC C++** and I have derived a `CDockablePane` object that I can view on the main window. I need the dockable pane's background to be *transparent* so you can see the main window through the dockable pane.

How would I accomplish this? Thanks.
this how i create the CDockable Pane object:

```
if (!FeaturePane.Create("Features", this, CSize (400,500), TRUE, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | CBRS_LEFT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create Program window\n");
        //return false; // failed to create
        return FALSE;
    }
```

i Know you can clear the background of a `CDroDialog` using the following code:

```
BOOL CDroDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(m_hWnd,GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(255,0,255),0, LWA_COLORKEY);
}


BOOL CDroDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
     CRect clientRect ;

     GetClientRect(&clientRect) ;

     pDC->FillSolidRect(clientRect, RGB(255,0,255)) ;  // paint background in magenta
    //return CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
     return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: are you sure? is there no way to just erase the background?

Comment: Erasing the background wouldn't help. That's not how GUIs work. It's not a layer of things you can just peel off. It's a single picture and once something paints on it, what's underneath is gone (since what's the point in preserving it?). You'd have to never paint the background in the first place and I don't think you can do that with MFC classes.

Comment: I may be wrong. Never claimed otherwise.

Comment: @jes: MFC has *nothing* to do with windowing or GUIs. It's a wrapper around an API that does. And the Windows API supports [layered windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows).

Comment: so can it be done?

Comment: Sure. It looks like you mostly solved this already. Just replace key-color with alpha transparency, and you should be done.

Comment: @IInspectable can you elaborate a little more? what should i replace? cause the code i have now doesnt do anything

Comment: Add the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style, and call [CWnd::SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#setlayeredwindowattributes) to control the amount of translucency.